# two set-intervals in a row gets executed like 1 interval

Tags: javascript

I'm working on canvas. I want to move an object to a hotel on my map. I want it to seem like an animation. So, the object should move from sreets and get to the goal (which is hotel). "MyGamePiece" is the object (Actually a rectangle) which i want to move. I have a function like this :

```
    function setIntervalX(callback, delay, repetitions) {
    var x = 0;
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {

       callback();

       if (++x === repetitions) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       }
    }, delay);
  }
```

I want to move my object to 1 position ( like an animation ). Wait a bit, And then move it to another position. This is what i'm doing now :

```
function move_to_hotel(){
    setIntervalX(function(){
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGamePiece.x-=0.5;
        myGamePiece.y-=0.5;
        myGamePiece.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    },100,15);
    setIntervalX(function(){
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGamePiece.x+=0.5;
        myGamePiece.y-=0.5;
        myGamePiece.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    },100,30);
  }
```

It doesn't really matter what the other functions are. ( Taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/games/game_obstacles.asp) ). The problem is that when i run the page, it seems that javascript combines these two movements and makes a new one ! I want it to execute the first function 15 times, then wait, after that, execute the second function( which is in the second interval ) 30 times. I don't know why it combines these two intervals and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are synchronously setting the intervals, and then asynchronously running each new function.... Either chain the functions, or do a semaphore to start/stop the functions.

Comment: As for chaining - you can make `setIntervalX` either accept a callback (that'll be fired when the repetitions are exhausted) or return a promise resolved in the same way.

Comment: @Bonatti i'm new to intervals sir ... would you please write the answer?

Comment: @raina77ow i didn't wrote the function "setIntervalX". I just copied it from another question on stackoverflow and used it for my project. So, if it doesn't suit my need, what should i do? would you please help ?

Comment: take a look at [greensocks animation framework](http://greensock.com/gsap) and it's timelines

Comment: start the 2nd interval from a setTimeout

Comment: @dandavis it's not just 2 intervals ! it may be 10 !

Comment: doesn't change my advice. stagger timeouts as needed.

Comment: @dandavis would you please write an example as an answer?

Comment: @MaryamSeraj Be careful how you address people here. This is a community based forum, that aids each other. If you are rude, unnecessarily, people will just shun you away, and ignore you. Be polite, be gentle, and most of all, be thankfull that others are willing to help, cost free for you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution from what is requested, is to "chain" functions, i.e. have only one of them running at a time, them, on completion, run the next one.

> Before you start, add vars, to hold the data

```
var idHolders = [];
var functions = [];
var delays = [];
var repetitions = [];
```

> chain your functions by stacking them in sequence:

```
stackFunction(1, doFirstStuff(), 10, 2);
stackFunction(2, doSecondStuff(), 10, 2);
...
stackFunction(n, doNthStuffs(), 10, 2);
...
stackFunction(x, doLastStuff(), 10, 2);
// until all are stacked.
```

> Then, start your functions calls with nextFunction();

```
nextFunction();
```

> stackFunction is:

```
function stackFunction(id, function, delay repetition){
   idHolders.push(id);
   functions.push(function);
   delays.push(delay);
   repetitions.push(repetition);
}
```

> setIntervalRepeating is:

```
function setIntervalRepeating(callback, delay, repetitions) {
    var x = 0;
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
       callback();
       if (++x === repetitions) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalID);
           nextFunction();
       }
    }, delay);
}
```

> nextFunction is:

```
function nextFunction() {
   var id = idHolder.pop();
   var function = functions .pop();
   var delay = delays.pop();
   var repetition = repetitions .pop();
   if(id != undefined){
      setIntervalRepeating(function, delay, repetition);
   }
}
```

While this is not a best practice, it will guide you, on what you are doing, and what to read about in Javascript, I HIGHLY suggest reading [MDN material, on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)